# Exclude rows with particular text in a column while searching in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table using [datatable library](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searching), I want to exclude all the rows from search results that contain particular keyword say office from datatable in column 2.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Home |
| Cell 3 | Office |

I have tried 2 methods but both don't work

First Method

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        dom: '<"search-box-wrapper"f><"table-wrapper"t>',
    });

    // Add an id to the search box
    // $('.search-box-wrapper input').attr('id', 'my-search-box');

    // Re-draw the table when the search box is used
    console.log($('#myTable_filter input'));
    $('#myTable_filter input').unbind().bind('keyup', function() {
        table.search(this.value).draw();
    });

    // Add custom filtering
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
            // Get the data for the second column (index 1)
            var columnData = data[1];

            // Check if the column data contains the 'out_of_Service' text
            if (columnData.indexOf('out_Of_Service') !== -1) {
                // If it does, exclude this row from the search results
                return false;
            }

            // Otherwise, include this row in the search results
            return true;
        }
    );
```

2nd Method

```
var exclusionKeyword = "out_Of_service";
    var table;
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Initialize DataTable
        table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
                // Custom filtering function
                $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
                    // Get the content of the second column (index 1)
                    var columnContent = data[1]; // Assuming the keyword is in the second column
    
                    // Check if a search term has been entered by the user
                    var searchValue = table.search();
    
                    // If no search term is provided, include the row
                    if (!searchValue) {
                        return true;
                    }
    
                    // Check if the column content includes the search term
                    if (columnContent.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())) {
                        // Exclude rows containing "out_Of_service"
                        if (columnContent.toLowerCase().includes(exclusionKeyword.toLowerCase())) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
    
                    // Include all other rows in the search results
                    return true;
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.